# can't install windows phone 7.1 sdk on vs2012 in windows 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I have tried to install windows phone 7.1 sdk on vs2012 but I can't install most of the components. I have windows 8. I have a normal version of windows 8 so I can't debug windows phone 8 apps so I have to install sdk 7.1 but lots of errors. 
the error screenshot is as below.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: What did u mean by "normal version of windows"? a not activated one? then i think the best option is to install Visual Studio 2010 and then install windows phone SDK 7.1, but then you won't able to develop windows phone 8 apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone SDK 7.1 can't be installed on Windows 8 as you can see [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570) in System Requirements.

You should install [Windows Phone SDK 8](http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk) in Windows 8.

You can develop apps for both Windows Phone 7.5+ and Windows Phone 8 with this SDK.

Comment: thank you for solving my confusion. working on windows phone 8 now.